Thomassen's proof of the Jordan-Schönflies theorem: existence of plane-isomorphic graph
This question is about a step in Thomassen's proof of the Jordan-Schönflies theorem (Theorem 3.1 in this paper, page 8 of the pdf).

Relevant background
I will quote the relevant part of the theorem for this question.

Theorem 3.1. If $f$ is a homeomorphism of a simple closed curve $C$ onto a simple closed curve $C'$, then $f$ can be extended into a homeomorphism of the whole plane.
Proof: Without loss of generality, we can assume that $C'$ is a convex polygon. We shall first extend $f$ to a homeomorphism of $\overline{\text{int}}(C)$ to $\overline{\text{int}}(C')$. [...] Let $\Gamma_0$ denote any $2$-connected graph consisting of $C$ and some simple polygonal arcs in $\overline{\text{int}}(C)$. Let $\Gamma_0'$ be a graph consisting of $C'$ and simple polygonal arcs in $\overline{\text{int}}(C')$ such that $\Gamma_0$ and $\Gamma_0'$ are plane-isomorphic (with isomorphism $g_0$) such that $g_0$ and $f$ coincide on $C \cap V(\Gamma_0)$. [...]

The definition of plane-isomorphism is given right before the theorem statement:

If $C$ and $C'$ are simple closed curves and $\Gamma$ and $\Gamma'$ are $2$-connected graphs consisting of $C$ (respectively, $C'$) and simple polygonal arcs in $\overline{\text{int}}(C)$ (respectively, $\overline{\text{int}}(C')$), then $\Gamma$ and $\Gamma'$ are said to be plane-isomorphic if there is an isomorphism of $\Gamma$ to $\Gamma'$ such that a cycle in $\Gamma$ is a face boundary of $\Gamma$ iff the image of the cycle is a face boundary of $\Gamma'$ and such that the outer cycle of $\Gamma$ is mapped onto the outer cycle of $\Gamma'$.

Also $\overline{\text{int}}(C)$ means the interior of $C$ together with its boundary (in the sense of the Jordan Curve Theorem, which was already proven earlier in the paper).

The question
How do we construct the graph $\Gamma_0'$ in $\overline{\text{int}}(C')$ that is plane-isomorphic to $\Gamma_0$ with the isomorphism agreeing with $f$ on the vertices of $\Gamma_0$ lying on $C$?

My thoughts
Let $G$ be the graph obtained from $\Gamma_0$ by deleting the vertices lying in $C$, as well as the edges that are adjacent to these vertices. We are left with a graph lying in $\text{int}(C)$. Since $G$ is a compact subset, there is a disk of radius $r \gt 0$ that contains it. We have a homeomorphism $g_0$ from $G$ to a graph $G’$ contained in $\text{int}(C')$ (by scaling $G$ until it lies in a sufficiently small disk fitting inside $\text{int}(C’)$, and translating if necessary). Then $g_0$ is also a plane isomorphism from $G$ to $G’$ (scaling and translation preserve planarity).
We also define $g_0$ such that $g_0(v_i) = f(v_i)$ for each vertex $v_i$ in $C \cap V(\Gamma_0)$.
But now we need to connect $g_0(v_i)$ with the vertices in $G'$ in a way that preserves plane-isomorphism (i.e. define the images of the edges that were deleted previously, in a way that avoids self intersections and maps face boundaries to face boundaries).
I can't think of a rigorous way to construct this even though it looks "obvious". Since we're going through the trouble of proving an already "obvious" theorem, it seems that we cannot rely on anything being obvious, so I am hoping there is a convincing way to achieve this. There is also a difficulty because $f$ could in principle "reverse" the orientation of the vertices on $C'$ and then connecting these vertices to $G'$ might involve intersections.
